# Python - Principal component analysis (PCA) error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, pca

I am trying to make Principal component analysis (PCA) using python. Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

#Step1: put database images into a 3D array
filenames = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder/*.pgm')
filenames.sort()
img = [Image.open(fn).convert('L') for fn in filenames]
images = np.dstack([np.array(im) for im in img])    

# Step2: create 2D flattened version of 3D input array
d1,d2,d3 = images.shape
b = np.zeros([d1,d2*d3])
for i in range(len(images)):
  b[i] = images[i].flatten()

#Step 3: PCA
results = PCA(b)
results.Wt
```

but I am getting an error `RuntimeError: we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols`

I tried replacing `b = np.zeros([d1,d2*d3])` by `b = np.zeros([d2*d3, d1])` I got `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2760) into shape (112)`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you change to `b = np.zeros([d2*d3, d1])` you should also change the loop afterwards otherwise you try to put a `d1` dimention array into a `d2*d3` one.</strike>

You should get rid of the second error doing this

You can simply transpose `b`

```
# Step2: create 2D flattened version of 3D input array
d1,d2,d3 = images.shape
b = np.empty([d1,d2*d3])  #if you know that you are filling the whole array it's faster that using np.zeros or np.ones
for i, im in enumerate(images): 
    b[i,:] = im.flatten()

#Step 3: PCA
results = PCA(b.T)
```

I've also substituted your for loop with what I think is a better version: in your implementation you first find the dimension of `images`, create a list of integers loop over it and then re-access `images`. `enumerate` returns an iterator with a couple (index, value). The advantages are that it returns just the elements that you need, and then you don't have to access `images` directly in the loop.

Probably you also don't need to create `images`, but I don't know `PIL`, so there I can't help you. In that case, you can simply get the dimensions with something like

```
d1,d2,d3 = len(img), img[0].shape
```

---

**EDIT**

you if you want you can also convert the content of the files to numpy when reading them.

For the records, this is [`numpy.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got your point and I find it more logical, but when trying the code you've suggested to get rid of the second error I got another error: `AttributeError: flatten`

Comment: I was assuming that the elements of `img` were numpy arrays. See my edit

Comment: again I got an error similar to the second error : `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10304) into shape (2760)`

Comment: Me stupid. What happens if you use your code and just substitute `results = PCA(b)` with `result = PCA(b.T)`?

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I'll edit my answer then. Can you check if you need to create `images` or it's fine to use `enumerate(img)`?

Comment: no it doesn't work `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10304) into shape (2760)`